Vaadin 24 Drag and Drop
I'm trying to get drag'n drop working with Vaadin 24. Should be an easy thing. But somehow, it simply does not work. This is my code:
public DashboardView() {

        System.out.println("View loaded!");

        // Drag-Quelle
        Div dragSourceDiv = new Div(new Text("Drag me!"));
        dragSourceDiv.getStyle()
                .set("padding", "20px")
                .set("background-color", "lightgray")
                .set("cursor", "grab");
        DragSource<Div> dragSource = DragSource.create(dragSourceDiv);
        dragSource.setEffectAllowed(EffectAllowed.MOVE);
        dragSource.addDragStartListener(event -> System.out.println("Drag started!"));

        // Drop-Ziel
        Div dropTargetDiv = new Div();
        dropTargetDiv.setWidth("300px");
        dropTargetDiv.setHeight("300px");
        dropTargetDiv.getStyle()
                .set("border", "3px dashed blue")
                .set("background-color", "yellow");
        DropTarget<Div> dropTarget = DropTarget.create(dropTargetDiv);
        dropTarget.setDropEffect(DropEffect.MOVE);
        dropTarget.addDropListener(event -> {
            System.out.println("Drop-Event!");
            event.getDragSourceComponent().ifPresent(source -> {
                System.out.println("Widget dropped: " + source.getElement().getText());
            });
        });

        add(dragSourceDiv, dropTargetDiv);
    }

Unfortunately, it does not work. "Drop-Event!" is never printed on screen.
What am I doing wrong?
thanks,
Thorsten

this code worked fine for me. Added the below line and i do see the text appearing in dropTargetDiv.
Div droppedItem = new Div(new Text(source.getElement().getText()));
dropTargetDiv.add(droppedItem);

So this code worked? What Version of Vaadin do you use exactly?


com.vaadin
vaadin-bom
24.6.0.alpha1
pom
import

Works like a charm with Vaadin 24.6.0 and also older versions.
